# Coverage by intersecting smaller genomic interval data over larger genomic intervals using R

Tags: r

I want to intersect two genomic intervals in R. And I want to get coverage stats of the smaller interval over the larger interval.

The larger interval data is a data frame like this ....

```
Chr  Start     End       Name         Val    Strand
chr7 145444998 146102295 CCDS5889.1   0      +
chr7 146102406 146167735 CCDS5889.1   0      +
chr7 146167929 146371931 CCDS5889.1   0      +
```

the smaller interval with more than 2 million rows is like this .

```
Chr  Start     End       Name         Val    Strand PhyloP   
chr7 145444386 145444387 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764
chr7 145444387 145444388 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764
chr7 145444388 145444389 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764
chr7 145444389 145444390 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764
```

The interval data is in the 2nd (from) and 3rd (to) columns in both data frame.

The situation is similar to

```
Large Interval:    [-----]   [-----]     [--------------]   [-------------------]
Small Interval: |||  ||||  |||||||||||  ||||||||   ||||  || |||||||||   ||    ||||||||
```

1. I want to know how much of each of the larger intervals is covered by the smaller intervals.
2. Also, I would to associate the intersecting $PhyloP values for each of the large intervals for later access for plotting.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bioconductor IRanges and GenomicRanges packages have `findOverlaps`, `countOverlaps`,  `coverage` and other interval-based functions that are designed to do these operations. You'd use the `GRanges` function to represent each of the `subject` ("larger intervals") and `query` ("smaller intervals") objects above. See the [installation instructions](http://bioconductor.org/install/) and then vignettes, e.g., `browseVignettes("GenomicRanges")`

In a little more detail, here's your data

```
sdf <- read.table(textConnection(
"Chr  Start     End       Name         Val    Strand
chr7 145444998 146102295 CCDS5889.1   0      +
chr7 146102406 146167735 CCDS5889.1   0      +
chr7 146167929 146371931 CCDS5889.1   0      +"), header=TRUE)

qdf <- read.table(textConnection(
"Chr  Start     End       Name         Val    Strand PhyloP   
chr7 145444386 145444387 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764
chr7 145444387 145444388 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764
chr7 145444388 145444389 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764
chr7 145444389 145444390 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764"), header=TRUE)
```

and here we convert these to `GRanges` and find the intersection between query and subject

```
library(GenomicRanges)
subj <-
    with(sdf, GRanges(Chr, IRanges(Start, End), Strand, Val=Val))
query <-
    with(qdf, GRanges(Chr, IRanges(Start, End), Strand, Val=Val,
                      PhyloP=PhyloP, names=Name))
intersect(query, subj)
```

The answer isn't very exciting here

```
> intersect(query, subj)
GRanges with 0 ranges and 0 elementMetadata values
     seqnames ranges strand |

seqlengths
 chr7
   NA
```

To be a little more useful, here's a query that tiles across your total region

```
tiles <- successiveIRanges(rep(100, 950), 900, 145444998)
query <- GRanges("chr7", tiles, "+")
```

We find the intersecting ranges, find which subject is overlapped by each intersecting range, and summarize the width of the overlapping ranges

```
int <- intersect(query, subj)
tapply(int, subjectHits(findOverlaps(int, subj)),
       function(x) sum(width(x)))
```

leading to

```
    1     2     3 
65800  6500 20400
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Was useful. How do you perform the same if the query is not an interval but just single points within the subject?  say like this ..."chr7 145444386 CCDS5889.1   0      +      0.684764"

Comment: Also how do I perform exploratory analysis on "PhyloP" values in the query interval that map to each of the larger subject interval (like say, boxplots, mean..ect)?

Comment: For single points, treat them either as intervals with width 1 `GRanges("chr7", IRanges(145444386, width=1))` or as real points `GRanges("chr7", IRanges(145444386, width=0))`. Not sure exactly what you mean about PhyloP; `olap = findOverlaps(query, subject)` returns an object that you can use to index into query and subject, e.g., `tapply(values(query)[["PhyloP"]][queryHits(olap)], subjectHits(olap), sum)`.